# How do I set a colour to be transparent in a GIF using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I've had a hard time finding out how to set a colour (black in my case) to be transparent in a GIF using ImageMagick. How can I do that to a set of existing GIF images?

I've tried this option but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
mogrify -transparent-color black -transparent black *.gif
```

I've read through this but it seems a little baffling in what actually makes a colour become transparent in a GIF: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#boolean_trans

For example:

> Note that setting "-transparent-color" does NOT add any transparency
>   to a GIF image, nor does it convert the specified color to become
>   transparent. All the option does is specify what color should placed
>   in the color table for the color index that is used representing the
>   transparent colors in a GIF image.
>
> If you want to change a specific (exact) color to become transparent,
>   then use the "-transparent" Color Replacement Operator.

but then...

> Use +transparent to invert the pixels matched. that is make all
>   non-matching colors transparent.
>
> The -opaque operator is exactly the same as -transparent but replaces
>   the matching color with the current -fill color setting, rather than
>   transparent. However the -transparent operator also ensures that the
>   image has an alpha channel enabled, as per "-alpha set", and does not
>   require you to modify the -channel to enable alpha channel handling.
>
> Note that this does not define the color as being the 'transparency
>   color' used for color-mapped image formats, such as GIF. For that use
>   -transparent-color

Comment: your image was originally a GIF or you created it by renaming?

Comment: The image was originally PNG, but I have converted them all to GIFs now.

Comment: which command line you use for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to warn you from using `mogrify`. `mogrify` does convert images by overwriting the original ones. If anything goes wrong, your images are gone.

Rather use `convert`. You can always delete your original images after you are sure the conversion is ok.

To make black pixels transparent, use this:

```
convert orig.gif -transparent black transp.gif
```

Works perfectly for me.

My IM version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-0 2012-07-04 Q16. What's yours?

If it still doesn't work for you, the 'black' in your GIFs may not be black after all, but only very dark gray. ImageMagick also has tools to enumerate all colors in a GIF. The following 2 commands may help you in this case:

```
 identify \
   -format "%f: - Uniq Colors: %k - Image transparency channel enabled: %A - Image Depth: %z %c\n" \
    *.gif
```

and

```
 convert \
     *.gif \
    -format "%f :\n%c\n\n" \
     histogram:info:
```

Use of color black can be identified by name 'black', by RGB-values '(0, 0, 0)' as well as by hex value '#000000'. So pure blacks should appear in the output of the last command as something like:

```
 5000: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
```

Dark grays could for example be:

```
  100: ( 14, 14, 14,255) #0E0E0E srgba(14,14,14,1)
 2100: (  1,  1,  1,255) #010101 srgba(1,1,1,1)
```

Once there is transparency enabled in your GIF, the last command should show a tuple of 4 values for each color, the last value representing the Alpha channel. Your formerly black would appear in the output as something like:

```
 5000: (  0,  0,  0,  0) #00000000 none
```

Comment: Note that in Windows you should probably specify the full path to convert.exe or you'll execute a different command ;): `CONVERT volume /FS:NTFS [/V] [/CvtArea:filename] [/NoSecurity] [/X]`

Comment: Apparently, my "green screen" isn't pure. Per https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29615 and http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29224 I had to do this but it had some serious artifacts:
convert mess.gif -fuzz 40% -transparent "#3f793f" disaster7.gif

Answer (score -3):

Try -background color once you generate it to GIF.

Check the http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php url for both mogrify and background options. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry could you give me an example of that in use?

Comment: How does "-background color" make a colour transparent? It doesn't say that in your link anywhere.